# How to debug and deploy my class library that is really a VSX Extension?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, vsx

The Class Library is an Microsoft Studio extension that generates a file from saving running a custom tool on a template file, following the module from this example I found from Microsoft: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SingleFileGenerator/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4138.

I can not figure out how I'm gonna debug, build, or deploy this object so I can test it in Microsoft Studio 2010. If you can help me get my class library debugging inside the VSX instance let me know. I will also need to compile and have a delivery method for this extension.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a new project using the template under Visual Basic -> Extensibility -> Visual Studio Package and then move your existing code into that. The project produced from the template will be automatically set up for debugging in the Experimental Instance.